# L4: use Redirect class in workbench

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I want to use the `Redirect::to()` of laravel 4 into my new package and I know that it must be called externally `http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.Redirector.html` but no luck. I use to put this before the class name: `use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector as Redirect` but it didn't work. Anyone there who encountered or knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I discover a solution. Just use `Redirect` in your class. Put `use \Redirect` before you class header.

Comment: You can also call the Redirect class via `\Redirect` without having to include `use \Redirect`.